# How to get type from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array where I want to get the `type` and (if any is set) `amount` value (default amount should be 1). How do I do so?

```
array(10)  { 

[0]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(7) "BEER" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(8) "BEEF" ["amount"]=> int(3) } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "WOOD" } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "CHEESE" } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 
[7]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 
[8]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 
[9]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(3) "EMPTY" } 

}
```

EDIT: Well, I've already tried it with an foreach, like I did before.. But since this is no JSON anymore I died

```
foreach($json as $key => $moreJson)
{
    $json[$key] = json_decode($moreJson);
}

echo '<p> User data for Player is 1 ', $json['type'][3];
```

But this gave me:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in XX on line 19
```

Comment: `$array[0]['type']` and `$array[0]['amount']`?

Comment: Provide some code you tried and tell us what went wrong before asking for someone to do everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    if( !array_key_exists('amount',$item) ){
        $item['amount'] = 1;
    }
    $new_array[] = $item;
}
```

Or even better without the curly braces, as we are only doing one line of code in the if statement.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    if( !array_key_exists('amount',$item) )
        $item['amount'] = 1;
    $new_array[] = $item;
}
```

Or even better without the $new_array and braces. You can use the & to assign that array value by reference.

```
foreach($array as &$item)
    if( !array_key_exists('amount',$item) )
        $item['amount'] = 1;
```

Comment: Nice code! I'm just wondering why you have to set $array as $item. Can't you use it directly?

Comment: See http://php.net/foreach for more info :)
It loops through every array and $items contains each array in the loop

Comment: You can also look up on array_push and see what it does ref. http://php.net/array_push

Comment: Hello again, I would just like to ask if following would work (to skip EMPTY slots) if( !array_key_exists('amount',$item) && $array['type'] != 'EMPTY' )

Comment: I guess so. I need a little bit of context in your example. Shouldn't you use `$item['type'] != 'EMPTY'`